# openssl.cafile with no value for web requests only

Tags: php, openssl

In a fresh Valet installation I've updated within my php.ini:

`openssl.cafile = "/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem"`

Then, within my Laravel `public/index.php` I'm outputting my `phpinfo();` on line 1.

If I then perform a request via Postman I can see:

```
<tr class="h">
    <th>Directive</th>
    <th>Local Value</th>
    <th>Master Value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="e">openssl.cafile</td>
    <td class="v"><i>no value</i></td>
    <td class="v"><i>no value</i></td>
</tr>
```

However the expected result I can see via tinker is:

```
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
openssl.cafile => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem
```

As far as I understand both requests should load the same file, yet that doesn't happen.

In both cases loaded php.ini is the same:

```
<tr>
    <td class="e">Loaded Configuration File </td>
    <td class="v">/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini </td>
</tr>
```

```
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

I've already tried copying the pem to a different folder, but either way it's not loaded for web requests. What can I do?

Comment: CLI and CGI executions are frequently performed with differing config files, and PHP usually loads more than just one config file. What about the "Additional .ini files parsed" section? Does that match as well?

Comment: @Sammitch Yup, they do match and there're no overrides within additionally included files (in my case it's `ext-opcache.ini` and `php-memory-limits.ini` within `conf.d`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what the reason for this is, but as a workaround I've:

- copied `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem` to `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/cacert.pem`
- set `curl.cainfo = "/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/cacert.pem"` within my php.ini file

This way at least given file is always included